# Passing custom variables to paypal IPN using API

Tags: paypal

I am using paypal API for subscription.
I Want to pass custom variable in IPN like user id so that I can save the id in database and show user only his transactions.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you could do that.

If you have an invoice ID of some sort that's already related back to your customer then you could just pass that invoice ID into the INVNUM parameter of your API request.  That way it will come back in the "invoice" parameter in IPN, and then you can use your existing relationships to pull back out your customer ID and save the new transaction for that customer ID.

Alternatively, you could just use the CUSTOM parameter in your API requests which allows you to pass any string you want up to 256 characters. If that one value is all you need then you could just store it alone and pull it out of IPN using the "custom" parameter there.  If you need to pass more than 1 custom value you could include them all in a string like "val1|val2|val3|etc" and parse that out of the custom parameter that IPN sends you.